# Why does Play only provides support for OAuth 1.0?

Tags: oauth, playframework

**Aim:** to authenticate to a Scala Play Framework using Google

**Attempt**

According to [this documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaOAuth):

> Version 2 is simple enough to be implemented easily without library or
>   helpers, so Play only provides support for OAuth 1.0.

**Discussion**

[This](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate) and [another](https://github.com/ntenisOT/play-authenticate-mongo) example were found, but it seems that some classes need to be copied. I am looking for a library that can be imported and called in the classes. I do not want to copy code. According to the documentation `Version 2 is simple enough to be implemented easily without library or helpers`, but were could an example be found? Why does Play only provides support for OAuth 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3rd part libraries.

I prefer [pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j), it's easy to configure and use. You can use both scala and java, and you can use it in a lot of java frameworks, like Spring.

You can find other authentification libraries as well: 
[Authentication (Login & Registration) and Authorization (Restricted Access)](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ModuleDirectory#Authentication-(Login-&-Registration)-and-Authorization-(Restricted-Access))